# Unicode Characters in Mutt Attachments

Tags: mutt, unicode

I'm looking for a way to get mutt to properly display Unicode characters when selecting and saving attachments.

I will often see a line like this in mutt

```
 A 6 =?UTF-8?B?MS0yIEZhbiAyIFBhcmFtZXRlcnMg6Y      [applica/pdf, base64, 56K]
```

while the actual title of the document is

```
1-2 Fan 2 Parameters 选型参数表_II.pdf
```

Needless to say, when there are more than a few of these documents attached to an email, it's quite difficult to tell them apart and save them efficiently if need be.

I don't have an issue viewing Unicode characters in subject lines or in message bodies.

The `charset` for my mutt is "UTF-8". I'm using the apt-get version of mutt (1.5.24) on Lubuntu. Mutt is pointed at a Gsuite account, if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm using 1.5.21 and attachment names with UTF-8 encoding are rendered correctly. No special settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the explanations of `rfc2047_parameters` in manual for `muttrc` for details.

Simply add,

```
set rfc2047_parameters = yes
```

to your `.muttrc`

Comment: Thanks! The weird part is that the manual says this is on by default, and somehow I permanently turned it off without using my .muttrc.

Comment: my `man muttrc` says that it is off by default